# Complain - moderator edited my question so that it became duplicated then closed it

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, moderation

I have asked a question about how to draw lines without antialiasing in Photoshop. My goal was just to draw straight lines without antialiasing and nothing more (or less).

First a moderator asked "with which tool" in comments. I answered him/her that I don't care which tool to use but just want the described result.

Is this wrong to wish some artifact being drawn with particular graphic software? Or it was not clear what I wish?

Nevertheless I have updated my question with the picture of lines with and without antialising to illustrate what I want since I got some down votes. Meanwhile the question was closed by that moderator as not a question.

Trying to receive an answer, I wrote here about the closure and many people voted my question up because they were thinking it was ok. I got 5 upvotes and 4 downvotes totally. Also I was advised to update my question and flag it which I have done.

Nevertheless my question was not opened. Moreover, the same moderator have edited my question so that it became a duplicate of general question about antialising (which he/she was not knowing what it is previously) and change the close reason to duplication.

I think this moderator just abuses his/her authority not to recognize his/her wrongness. Is it possible to avoid somehow of his/her abuse?

My question is here now: [How to draw a line wich is 1 pixel width and many pixels length without anti-aliasing?](https://superuser.com/questions/426046/turn-off-anti-aliasing-in-photoshop)

I don't know how to see the history, but heard it is possible.

Comment: But if you don't have a specific goal or tool, then what value is the question? What problem does it solve? Just knowing if something is possible or not isn't really a good question

Comment: I wished to know how to draw the thing with Photoshop. Isn't this a specific goal? I am not a Photoshop guru, so I don't know which tool to use. This was the part of the question. I expected someone say me: take this tool, press that button and you will be done.

Comment: To view the history, just click the timestamp on the "Last edited by ___" line.

Comment: Your question was unfortunate to get the attention of one of the moderators. It happens. Note that it was closed by a moderator, then reopened by five community members, then closed for a different reason by the same moderator. Did you check out the question linked in the duplication notice? Maybe the second closing was appropriate?

Comment: @IvoFlipse Any chance we could get the comments to the question back, or at least in this Meta topic?

Comment: [There you are @DanielBeck](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nJmXi.png)

Comment: @SuzanCioc Your last question revision [was this](http://superuser.com/revisions/426046/4). Please explain in what ways the meaning of the Q was changed by the moderator as to no longer reflect your intent, and how it doesn't match the duplicate question. If you could show how your question was actually different in meaning, that would go a long way to reopening it.

Comment: The second closing was appropriate but the question was changed. I still do not know how to draw lines with no anti-alias. I found only the way to draw it in by-pixel manner.

Comment: @Daniel I was cornered trying to find appropriate spelling of the question so it can be accepted. May be I made a mistake and my last version was not exact. Actually my question is about lines. I need to draw straight black line with no partial color nearby, that's all.

Comment: We do change questions to clarify them, make them easier to read, or even more widely applicable, if it doesn't change the original intent of the question. If doesn't even need a moderator to do that, any experienced user on the site can edit questions. Your question appears to now be identical to revision 4, except for the wording and the reference to the custom shape tool. The question linked as the "original" to your duplicate appears to match as well, it just doesn't have a good answer for your situation. That's a known problem with duplicates. You could offer a bounty, or improve the Q.

Comment: @Daniel, My question is how to draw lines. It is hard to draw them by one pixel. If it was not criticized I would leave revision 1, since it is the most precise and appropriate version of the question. But I can't edit my question to revision 1 since moderator didn't recognized it's validity.

Comment: Please consider that the participants on this site help for free in their spare time, even those with the diamond next to their name. They (we) expect some basic effort by those looking for help, which includes well thought out questions and trying to communicate clearly. Your question, at least in its original version. really wasn't good. Closing the bad questions, at least until they're significantly improved, and moving on to the next one is a sensible approach, given limited time. If your question is not actually a duplicate, please explain how; and we can try to get it reopened.

Comment: Please dear @Daniel, can you explain me, WHY my initial question was bad? I really don't understand this.

Comment: I don't know a lot about Photoshop, but answering the questions random posts as an example in your other meta topic might be a start. They seem to be quite legitimate. Your comment to the question contained more information that the question never did, as well. That your example showed curved lines and you mention straight lines in the comment didn't help either.

Comment: In summary, I see no fault with the moderator(s) in handling this question, and nothing happened that isn't undoable after you explain how and why it doesn't apply to your specific question *by adding an explanation and more details to the question*. That the duplicate "original" question doesn't have the answer you need is unfortunate, but a different issue altogether.

Comment: @Daniel, what do you say if I say that finally I found a way to draw lines without anti-aliasing? This is what it sounds as -- just an answer to my initial question (revision 1).

Comment: AFAICT, and you don't seem opposed ("*The second closing was appropriate*"), it might be an appropriate answer to the question yours was closed as a duplicate of. You could post it there, as an answer.

Comment: No, the answer doesn't match the "duplicated" question. That question asks about general possibility to turn anti-aliasing off. I don't know how to turn it off in all situations. But I know now, how to draw namely lines without anti-aliasing. I.e. I know the answer to my initial question. Where to post it?

Comment: Please edit this question to quote your new found answer so that we can help determine the next course of action

Answer (score 2):

The previous versions of the question can be found by clicking on the "edited by {user}" link. The first version was found to be lacking information about what tools or settings have been tried in achieving the desired result.

> #### [How to draw 1 pixel line wiothout antialiacing?](https://superuser.com/revisions/426046/1)
>
> Is it possible to draw exact 1 pixel width line in photoshop starting from one exact pixel and ending in another one?

In most cases these questions are summarily closed. In this instance the first comment tried to extract more information that would be helpful in making the question more constructive:

> Horizontal? Diagonally? Bezier curved? With a pencil? With a custom shape? What are you trying and do you have an example?

You did clarify that what you wanted was:

> Only result matters, tool is irrelevant. I need a straight line of same color without anti-aliacing. Suppose only vertical or horizontal, but diagonal would be ok to know also.

While it would have been preferable to edit the question with this updated information to help better answer the question and to not have people ask more comments about what else has been attempted, [the subsequent edit added an image about anti-aliasing](https://superuser.com/revisions/426046/4).

By that time it was reopened. It was then again closed as a duplicate of a question asking about [how to disable anti-aliasing in Photoshop](https://superuser.com/questions/375493/can-i-disable-anti-aliasing-in-photoshop).

If the other question about how to turn off anti-aliasing does not match with the desired in your question, that is a fair cop.

Comment: So, you want to say that you closed the question because my answer to your question was located in comment but not in the question body? If so then why didn't you copy my comment to the body instead of closing? Or you could tell me to do so. How one can know that clarifications can't be located in comments?

Comment: So, I suggest the following question text:

Comment: How to draw 1 pixel width line without anti-aliasing?

Is it possible to draw exact 1 pixel width line in Photoshop? Starting from one exact pixel and ending in another one? Only result matters, tool is irrelevant. I need a straight line of same color without anti-aliasing.

Comment: Will you close it?